# Handling LinkButton event of dynamicaly generated table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to handle click event of link button which is dynamically created.

But i am not getting btn.click for it.

I have following code:

```
Public Sub test()
        Dim row As New HtmlTableRow()
        Dim cell As New HtmlTableCell()


        For i = 0 To 10
            row = New HtmlTableRow()
            For j = 0 To 3
                cell = New HtmlTableCell()
                cell.InnerText = "m"
                Dim btn1 As New LinkButton
                btn1.ID = i

                cell.Controls.Add(btn1)
                row.Cells.Add(cell)
            Next
            tableContent.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
    End Sub
```

C# Code:

```
public void test()
{
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();


    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        row = new HtmlTableRow();
        for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.InnerText = "m";
            LinkButton btn1 = new LinkButton();
            btn1.ID = i;

            cell.Controls.Add(btn1);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        tableContent.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Not getting intellisence on btn1.click:

[image]

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer in c# can also help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For VB.NET, type `AddHandler btn1.` and then you should see the `Click` event in the Intellisense, like this:

```
AddHandler btn1.Click, AddressOf Me.LinkButton_OnClick
```

---

Since you have dynamic content (table), you will need to rebuild the table on every page load, not just the first. The reason for this is that the `Page_Load` happens before the link button click event, so by the time the click event happens the table needs to have been recreated; otherwise your click event handler will try to interact with content that is not there.

---

Read [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more information about the page life cycle and all the events and their order.

Comment: after pasting this all the table created dynamicali got vanished

Comment: Are you rebuilding the table on each post back (i.e. `Page_Load` event)?

Comment: nope i have given condition if not postback then only calling the method

Comment: That is your problem, you need to re-build the table on every post back, remove the condition and the table will be there every click (post back). If you are not aware, the `Page_Load` happens before the link button click event in the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle. See updated answer.

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. - no problem, glad you got it working. Good luck to you. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In C# you can do:
1. Declare the handler

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

2. Assign the handler:

```
LinkButton btn1 = new LinkButton();
btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
```

Comment: i am not getting intelisence on l.click

Comment: You are trying that in VB. Please can you try in C#?

Comment: plz see last image under EDIT

Comment: @KevinHendricks means?

Comment: @KevinHendricks: I can't interpret what you are trying to say.

Comment: To clarify I was thinking you might miss a reference but I forgot the VB.NET syntax is quiet different when binding EventHandlers.

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S.: For VB, please try Karl's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add an event handler and an ID on the botton to be able to identify it:

```
public void test()
{
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();


    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        row = new HtmlTableRow();
        for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.InnerText = "m";
            LinkButton btn1 = new LinkButton();
            btn1.ID = i;

            // Add EventHandler for click events
            btn1.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_OnClick);

            cell.Controls.Add(btn1);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        tableContent.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Then add the following method to your code which catches the click events:

```
 protected LinkButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var button = (LinkButton)sender;
     // You can now access the id of the clicked link-button using button.ID
 }
```